# Automatic up-scrolling on mobile website experience

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Whenever [this site](http://joincamberwellrotary.org.au/) is viewed on a mobile device, it has unstable scrolling. Whenever the users try to enter their details in the contact form the site automatically scrolls upwards.

Scrolling downwards is also quite difficult with this automatic upscrolling.

I thought that the yellow "back to the top" button may have been causing the issue, so I deleted the code for that button to try and see if that was the cause- but it was not the case.

I don't exactly know what else that could be causing this issue...

**Code for the "back to the top" button:**

```
<div id="hs-back-top" class="animated bounceInRight">
   <i class="fa fa-angle-up">
     ::before == $0
   </i>
</div>
```

Comment: I just tested that site and it works properly. There is no jumping around unless you click the back to top button.

Comment: @Icewine actually there is a problem there

Comment: You have a method that returns nothing on the form click or scroll or whatever

Answer (score 0):

The page will scroll up to the top regardless of if the details have been added into the form that was created to enquire -

I wouldn't be able to say more without seeing all the code but what I can theorise is happening is:

When the code has completed running a function is being triggered that sends the page to the top:

This might be if the onclick function that the to top element is being triggered -

I had a issue like his before and had to pass the onClick or EventListener('click', function(){

})

to return a function that would take the page back to the top -

Sorry that's not more help but I can't make more comment on what is provided,

Hope this helps, 
W

Comment: The problem has been solved!
Scroll behavior CSS property added under Additional CSS was conflicting with scripts used by HashOne WP theme. Removing this custom code fixed the issue. According to HashOne's theme logs smoothscroll.js was removed in June 2019 as it was causing JS errors so I suspect there's some conflicts with existing library functions and this CSS property.